# How to change directory in terminal from a C file

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell

How to change the directory from a C program that will effect on the terminal.

Actually don't tell about system("") function or chdir("") function. Those work only the the process or the sub-shell in C.

Say I am execution a C program from a bash shell whose process id is 10223.
So, can I write a C code that will effect on the 10223 process which is a bash shell and whose path will be changed by my C program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<dirent.h>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std ;
int main(){

  system("pwd") ;
  chdir("test");
  system("pwd") ;
  return 0 ;
}
```

this change only until C code is running. after returning from C code how can I keep change the current environment.

UPD  1 :

in terminal if I write ps then I get the following output. Now can I have any function to execute a command via 10991 process. I think this solves the problem.

```
sbmaruf@kryptonyte:~$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
10991 pts/14   00:00:00 bash
11005 pts/14   00:00:00 ps
```

Comment: You can't change the current working directory of another process. Why would you even want to do that?

Comment: Ok I am writing a C code where I can change directory by inode value. Is it possible ?

Comment: After all, why do you need to cd by inode? What's the case where you know the inode but not the path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't. You cannot (*). The working directory is an attribute of a process. The terminal hosts a shell; that's a process. Your program is another process. Never the twain shall meet.

However, you are solving the wrong problem. Assume that you have a C program that converts an inode number to a path, and then prints the resulting path to standard output. Now, all you need is a shell alias that runs `cd $(my-program $1)`, and there you are -- a shell command that cd's by inode.

(*) If you write a program to attach to the shell process with `ptrace`, and you have the necessary permissions, you might be able to force the shell to change its working directory. However, since the shell *in particular* is maintaining things like `PWD`, the result of this may be incompletely effective.

You could write a shell function that ran at each prompt that checked for a file; if the file existed, the function would read it and set the working directory to the path in it. Probably this is not what you had in mind.

Since the shells you are using are open source (probably bash, perhaps zsh or fish), you might also consider making your own fork and adding your own extremely slow shell command that maps inode numbers to directories and cd's to them.

Comment: Ok I am writing a C code where I can change directory of the terminal by inode value. Is it possible ?

Comment: @Kryptonyte That doesn't make any sense. What is it that you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: To my knowledge, no you cannot, except, very tentatively, via ptrace.

Comment: I think that the OP wishes that the shell could cd by inode: http://askubuntu.com/questions/658092/how-to-cd-a-directory-without-writting-the-name-of-it.

Comment: U are referring to my thread .... that thread was created by me. I do not have the permission to ask question here by that account.

Comment: I have updated the problem statement. Can you please again see the statement. @bmargulies